# IDs from count query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table Orders:

```
O_Id    OrderDate   OrderPrice  Customer
1       2008/11/12  1000        Hansen
2       2008/10/23  1600        Nilsen
3       2008/09/02  700         Hansen
4       2008/09/03  300         Hansen
5       2008/08/30  2000        Jensen
6       2008/10/04  100         Nilsen
```

and query:

```
SELECT COUNT(Customer) AS CustomerNilsen FROM Orders
WHERE Customer='Nilsen'
```

but is possible add to this results IDs results?
I would like receive
**count: 2**
and
**ids: 2 and 6**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) may help:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(Customer) AS CustomerNilsen,
    GROUP_CONCAT(O_Id) as IDS
FROM
    Orders
WHERE
    Customer='Nilsen'
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to just fetch all the IDs and then use the appropriate row count function:

```
SELECT `O_Id` FROM `Orders`
WHERE `Customer` = 'Nilsen'
```

Comment: but how can i add for this COUNT?

Comment: What MySQL driver extension are you using? mysqli? PDO?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but from what I can tell you just want to `SELECT` the `o_id` column in your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(Customer) AS CustomerNilsen, O_Id AS OrderID FROM Orders WHERE Customer='Nilsen'
```

Comment: but this return me only first ID. I would like also for this example second ID

Answer (score 0):

You might check this

```
SELECT Customer,
         COUNT(Customer) AS CustomerNilsen  
    FROM Orders 
   WHERE Customer = 'Nilsen'
GROUP BY Customer
  HAVING CustomerNilsen  = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT O1.O_Id AS OrderID,Count(O1.O_Id) AS OrderCount FROM Orders  O1
INNER JOIN Orders  O2 ON O1.Customer = O2.Customer 
WHERE O1.Customer='Nilsen'
GROUP BY O1.Customer,O1.O_Id
```